# What happens with async await exactly?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, v8, internals, javascriptcore

I have such a piece of code

```
async function loop() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i,new Error("").stack);
    await 1;
  }
}

loop();
```

when I run it in Node (Chrome engine) I get this:

```
0 Error
    at loop (file:///Users/user/Desktop/test.mjs:3:19)
    at file:///Users/user/Desktop/test.mjs:8:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:308:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:42:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:66:12)
1 Error
    at loop (file:///Users/user/Desktop/test.mjs:3:19)
2 Error
    at loop (file:///Users/user/Desktop/test.mjs:3:19)
```

so it seems that after await the execution loses its broader context but retains the context of the function.

When I run the same piece of code in Bun (Safari engine) I get this:

```
0 Error: 
    at <anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/test.mjs:3:10)
    at loop (/Users/user/Desktop/test.mjs:1:22)
    at module code (/Users/user/Desktop/test.mjs:5:5)
1 Error: 
    at <anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/test.mjs:3:10)
2 Error: 
    at <anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/test.mjs:3:10)
```

which says that the execution loses even the context of the function.

Now, I know what happens when I use await like this, more or less. It forces stuff to be pushed to the micro task queue, lets the rest of the sync code on the stack execute, therefore we lose the stack, and picks up the stuff pushed to the queue afterwards.

However, I'm interested in how exactly this happens and looking at these different errors stacks I'm really confused. Are we in the same function after using await or is a new function created somehow with the context of the previous one?

Comment: `when I run it in Chrome` that's not the output ... that's Node output only, not Chrome

Comment: it's basically the same, the gist of it being the fact that `loop` appears in iterations 1 and 2

Comment: I guess you can deduce that `What happens with async await exactly?` depends on the javascript engine

Comment: "*It forces stuff to be pushed to the micro task queue*" - no it doesn't. It suspends the function execution and registers the remainder as a **promise handler**. It relies on the promise pushing the resumption onto the micro task queue, when the promise settles.

Comment: "*so it seems*" - don't read too much into stack traces. They are not standardised, and are not even guaranteed to represent what's actually on the stack. As for how V8 knows which function was suspended, see https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#improved-developer-experience

Comment: "*Are we in the same function after using await or is a new function created somehow with the context of the previous one?*" - does it really make a difference?

Comment: very useful comments, however it seems that the part about the micro task queue contradicts the answer that I marked as the correct one... I also don't like the "does it make a difference" remark. I tagged the question with "internals" because I don't care about the behaviour/functionality here, I care about how it actually works.

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski I don't think there's a mistake/contradiction in trincot's answer. It's just a common misunderstanding the the micro task is created/queued already when the `await` is evaluated, while actually it is only queued when the promise settles. But this is irrelevant for the what happens inside that task, the mechanism your question is asking about.

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski I'm not quite sure if you are asking about the internals of the `await` operator on a *conceptual* level (i.e. what the spec says) or really asking about the internals on the *implementation* level with the details of the C++ data structures representing the stack frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the execution loses even the context of the function.

I assume with "context" you refer to the execution contexts of the callers of the function. These contexts have been closed normally by their synchronous execution, while the execution context of the function itself is suspended.

An important realisation here is that the `async` function **returns** when it has evaluated an `await` expression. It returns a promise, and the call stack (what you call the "context") will run to completion. The call stack is empty, and will not be restored. Restoring it would make no sense, as it would indicate that a caller would get twice (or more) a return value from the `async` function, and code that follows that call would have to execute twice (or more) as well. A function only returns *once* to its caller.

So once the microtask is consumed, the execution context of the `async` function will be restored. But this does not include a restored call stack.

> Are we in the same function after using await or is a new function created somehow with the context of the previous one?

It is the same function -- it is resumed. See this as a new *call* of the function, but where it starts with a saved execution context, and continues from there. This time the caller is the event loop, so the call stack starts from scratch. When the `async` function executes a `return`, this return value will be used by the engine to resolve the promise that was returned to the original caller.

Comment: I guess it's extremely counter intuitive for me to think that a function both returns and still can be resumed. I get the concept of returning many times in generators, streams and stuff like that but with this it just makes my mind go bonkers. If the function returns on await then I guess it has to return every time an await statement gets interpreted? And then the stack of promises gets flattened to a single value that the async function returned?

Comment: The difference with a *second* await, is that it returns to a different caller, which in that second case is the engine (which executed the microtask). There is no flattening of promises involved here. The promise returned to the original caller will stay pending and will only resolve when the function executes a `return` statement (or has no more statements to execute).

Answer (score 0):

JS resolves a promise with a microtask that placed in the end of the current task.

You can read about microtasks in MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide

Your particular question about the stack difference is that the first time `loop()` is invoked by you directly in the script so the error's stack has the invocation line. The further after `await` the coded executed as a microtask and the "initializer" is JS itself so the `loop()` line disappears from the error's stack.

You can set a breakpoint and examine the stack in the dev console:

```js
async function loop() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    debugger;
    console.log(i,new Error("").stack);
    await 1;
  }
}

loop();
```

While `new Error('').stack` doesn't reflect the microtask, the dev console under `Call Stack` shows the actual stack's state:

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I wrote in the "I know that..." section

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski extended the answer, i hope that'd help